# Spring Boot: MongoDb: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(java.lang.Object)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-integration

**Prologue:**

I have researched this topic from the stackoverflow answers. All answers were pointed towards the dependency conflict, which in my case doesn't seem to be true. (*if i am not missing anything*)

**Problem:**

I am getting this exception during *runtime* when i use the `MongoTemplate` implementation `save` or `insert`

```
mongoTemplate.save(saveObject, COLLECTION)
mongoTemplate.insert(insertObject, COLLECTION)
```

There are no build issues or compilation issues.
The `save` or `insert` methods internally call `MongoCollection<TDocument>.insertOne(TDocument doc)` for my use case. If I implement this like below, it works fine :

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(COLLECTION);
collection.insertOne(docToSave);
```

**Debug:**

Also, If i put a debug point at `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate`

```
collectionToUse.insertOne(dbDoc);//exception is thrown from here
```

and execute it manually from the debugger, it works!

So there is no way that the Implementation is missing and judging from the `gradle dependencies` map, there seems to be no conflict as well.

here is my dependency structure:

```
+--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mongodb -> 5.4.5
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.4.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.3.5
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.5 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.5
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.5 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.1
|    |    \--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.4.4
|    |         \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3
|    \--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.1.6
|         \--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.4.6
+--- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.9
```

gradle file:

```
//project sensitive configurations omiited
..
//


plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'war'
}

//project sensitive configurations omiited
..
//

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.mongodb', module: 'mongodb-driver-core'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api'
    providedRuntime group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.44'
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat') {
        exclude group: 'org.mongodb', module: 'mongodb-driver-core'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
    }
    providedRuntime group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp-api', version: '2.3.3'
    implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mongodb') {
        exclude group: 'org.mongodb', module: 'mongodb-driver-core'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
    }
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.9'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4'
    implementation('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
    }
    implementation 'javax.mail:mail:1.4'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9-RC1'
    implementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
    implementation 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.8.1'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20141113'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.15'
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.0.2'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.15'
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:2.1.0'
    implementation 'net.sf.jxls:jxls-reader:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.efsavage.jquery:jquery-maven:1.7.2'
    implementation('cglib:cglib:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm'
    }
    implementation('org.springframework:spring-mock:2.0.8')
            {
                exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
                exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
            }
    implementation 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.2'
    implementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.2'
    implementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.2'
    implementation 'javax:javaee-web-api:7.0'

    //project sensitive configurations omiited
    ..
    //
}


//project sensitive configurations omiited
..
//
```

Exception:

```
2021-22-07 13:16:03 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] -
                Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/MY_ROOT_PATH] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.client.result.InsertOneResult com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(java.lang.Object)'] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.client.result.InsertOneResult com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(java.lang.Object)'
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$saveDocument$18(MongoTemplate.java:1505)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:561)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.saveDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1492)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:1370)
    at com.company.package.dao.mongo.MyDAOImpl.appendAndSave(MyDAOImpl.java:78)
    at com.company.package.dao.mongo.MyDAOImpl.saveFile(MyDAOImpl.java:50)
```

Comment: could you check dependency jar files, maybe there is more then one ```mongodb-driver``` jar file ?

Comment: @muhammedozbilici I did check that. There is just one mongo-java-driver-3.12.9.jar

Comment: And why do you try to exclude `mongodb-driver-core` and use your own dependecny for it instead of relying on whatever Spring Boot brings you as compatible version?

Comment: This was an old spring-mvc project with deprecated mongo. I am working on the DB migration and upgrade (server 3.4.21 to 4.2.12) with minimal code changes possible (upgrade to Spring Boot as well). Most of the DB operation were implemented around `mongo-java-driver` hence I am using it exclusively. Including `mongodb-driver-core` is not making any differences either, or causing any noticeable conflicts. Also, spring is not bringing the `mongo-java-driver` from the implementations I have in `build.gradle`. Hence, I just excluded `mongodb-driver-core` just to be sure of any chances of conflicts.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I thought about what you said and found out `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` brings down all the implementations the project required, including the implementations from `org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver` as `org.mongodb:mongo-driver-sync`. removing `spring-integration-mongodb` and `mongo-java-driver` and using just `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` fixed the issue! I think it's safe to assume that spring is looking for a compatible `org.mongodb:mongo-driver-sync` implementation. However, I would like to hear other's opinion on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `spring-integration-mongodb` and `mongo-java-driver` and using just `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` fixed the issue! I think it's safe to assume that spring is looking for a compatible `org.mongodb:mongo-driver-sync` implementation. However, I would like to hear other's opinion on this one.

FYI,
`spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` brings down all the implementations the project required, including the implementations from `org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver` as `org.mongodb:mongo-driver-sync`.

the changed `build.gradle` :

```
//project sensitive configurations omitted
...
//

plugins {
    //project sensitive configurations omitted
    ..
    //
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'war'
}

//project sensitive configurations omitted
...
//

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api'
    providedRuntime group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.44'
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
    }
    providedRuntime group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp-api', version: '2.3.3'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'


    // omitted unrelated dependencies for readability
    ...
    //

    //project sensitive configurations omitted
    ...
    //

}

//project sensitive configurations omitted
...
//
```

Comment: That's correct solution and right assumption. And that's indeed one of the main points of Spring Boot: to bring for your all the required and compatible dependencies and make your target burden about version management much easier. I can't find at the moment exact sentence about dependency management, but here is something closer than nothing: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.first-application.dependencies. You can accept your own answer.